# Domain directs to nginx default page instead of my root

Tags: nginx

Here is my server setup

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com

    root /root/sites/example.com;
    index index.html;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com www.subdomain.example.com;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/subdomain.example.com/static;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

`subdomain.example.com` is working fine. But when I go to `example.com` then it show nginx default welcome page.

Note: I deleted `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Need help to fix it.

Comment: What's the content of /root/sites/example.com ? What do you have in sites-enabled ?

Comment: It's a simple html site. `example.com` contains `index.html` and other `css` files.
`sites-enabled` has a file `examplme.com` which is symlink to `sites-available/example.com`. There is no other files in `sites-enabled`. I deleted `sites-enabled/default` but not `sites-available.default`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `;` after your server name. It should be:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your nginx settings

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

root /root/sites/example.com;
index index.html;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com www.subdomain.example.com;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/subdomain.example.com/static;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

Also comment out any default server settings in nginx.conf file.
You can alse include this servers setting under sites-enabled folder in a conf file( they will get included) and put the include command before any server tag in nginx.conf file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, the fix was that in the location section you need to add the trailing `/` so in your location you would add `/` after the *proxy-pass* statement. So:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once check the default config file for this issue.
I got the same issue and as I grep the default config file the domain was configured in that file. then I made the document root changes as per my need and the domain got started the document root which I have set